# Page refresh to local resource if server offline

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a question that may be difficult to answer. I developed an ASP application that is used to manage production and is accessed by procution staff via tablets while they are on production floor. One of my pages has a timer that refreshes the page to drop selected production item if no action was assigned to that item (logic of production).
Because tablets need to go to sleep to conserve energy, when they wake up, they have to reconnect to WiFi. It usually takes a second but browser can ask for a refresh before connection is reestablished and will display page unavailable message. I'd prefer that it didn't display that message, instead maybe direct itself to a local resource html that would have a button that user would click to redirect browser back to the server. This should be enough time for the wifi to reconnect and provide connection to IIS. So the question is how can I tell the browser to redirect to different location if expected page is not available?

Comment: Would using XMLHttpRequest (aka "ajax") be viable? If so, [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12882060/304683)....